# How to add 15 mins interval to date time series for every 2&3 row

Tags: r

I have dataframe as below

```
    Date_time        name
  11/1/2016 6:00      A
  11/1/2016 6:00      A
  11/1/2016 6:00      A
  11/1/2016 6:45      A
  11/2/2016 11:00     B
  11/2/2016 11:00     B
  11/2/2016 11:00     B
  11/2/2016 11:45     B
```

above df should be in 15 interval
we knoe after 00 mins, next one should be 15 & 30 & 45 intervals
O/p should be

```
Date_time        name   New_Date_time
  11/1/2016 6:00      A       11/1/2016 6:00 
  11/1/2016 6:00      A       11/1/2016 6:15     
  11/1/2016 6:00      A       11/1/2016 6:30     
  11/1/2016 6:45      A       11/1/2016 6:45     
  11/2/2016 11:00     B       11/2/2016 11:00    
  11/2/2016 11:00     B       11/2/2016 11:15
  11/2/2016 11:00     B       11/2/2016 11:30  
  11/2/2016 11:45     B       11/2/2016 11:45
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your variable `Date_time` is a character and that there are always 4 observations for each `name`. You can then do the following:

```
## Your data:
df <-  structure(list(Date_time = c("11/1/2016 6:00", "11/1/2016 6:00", 
    "11/1/2016 6:00", "11/1/2016 6:45", "11/2/2016 11:00", "11/2/2016 11:00", 
    "11/2/2016 11:00", "11/2/2016 11:45"), name = c("A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")), .Names = c("Date_time", "name"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>%
        dplyr::mutate(Date_time = as.POSIXct(Date_time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
        group_by(name) %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(New_Date_time = min(Date_time) + lubridate::minutes(c(0,15,30,45)))

df
# Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
# Groups: name [2]
# 
#             Date_time  name       New_Date_time
#                <dttm> <chr>              <dttm>
# 1 2016-11-01 06:00:00     A 2016-11-01 06:00:00
# 2 2016-11-01 06:00:00     A 2016-11-01 06:15:00
# 3 2016-11-01 06:00:00     A 2016-11-01 06:30:00
# 4 2016-11-01 06:45:00     A 2016-11-01 06:45:00
# 5 2016-11-02 11:00:00     B 2016-11-02 11:00:00
# 6 2016-11-02 11:00:00     B 2016-11-02 11:15:00
# 7 2016-11-02 11:00:00     B 2016-11-02 11:30:00
# 8 2016-11-02 11:45:00     B 2016-11-02 11:45:00
```

**Edit:**

If the number of observations varies, then just replace `c(0,15,30,45)` by `seq(from = 0, by = 15, length.out = n())`, i.e.:

```
df <- df %>%
        dplyr::mutate(Date_time = as.POSIXct(Date_time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
        group_by(name) %>% 
        dplyr::mutate(New_Date_time = min(Date_time) + 
                        lubridate::minutes(seq(from = 0, by = 15, length.out = n())))
```

Comment: thanks @ikop, what if the size of group varies.. in my case size of the groups are mismatch .. throwing the error like   "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :   incompatible size (4), expecting 8 (the group size) or 1  "

Comment: You could try replacing `minutes(c(0,15,30,45))` with `minutes(seq(from = 0, by = 15, length.out = n()))`